# Hide dropdown menu with overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css, reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-hill-lszyv?file=/src/App.tsx

I'm trying to hide the dropdown menu (the red box) by setting the parent container with overflow:hidden but that doesn't work, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Can hide it depend on `open` flag.

```
  {open && <ul className={styles.dropDownList}>
    {localesArr.map((locale, index) => {
      return (
        <li key={`${locale}-${index}`}>
          <a href="/">{locale}</a>
        </li>
      );
    })}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by setting the container div to position:relative